# Custom value slider unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider, letter

I want to return displayed value (a,b,c,d) not numbers (0.01-0.019 ect)
A help will be nice and many people will be happy.
This code look like percentage display but I dont want percentage I want a text

```
Mathf.RoundToInt(value * 100) + "%"
```

Comment: A bit confusing on what you're trying to do, do you mean number to text as in '50%' to 'fifty percent'?

Comment: No, I just want text when I drag the slider

Comment: @VaporMarin I added two solutions. One specifically for alphanumeric output and another for more general string values mapped to the numbers.

Comment: Make an array of texts .. use a slider with only full integer steps -> each step is an index to your array .. done

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a whole new custom slider, utilize what Unity already provides then map the output to whatever format you desire. Sliders can be set to have a fixed number of outputs as well as be fixed to only whole numbers.

[image: Example]

If you look at the slider component in the editor, the fields `Min Value`, `Max Value`, and `Whole Numbers` should be set. The most important is to set `Whole Numbers` to true and `Max Value` to the highest possible value - 1 of your new mapped set.

Next, when the value changes for your slider, you will want to set a callback delegate to your script to retrieve the value.

[image: Example 2]

You can either add the callback in the editor using the `UnityAction` UI in the editor or you can programmatically add the callback by accessing the `onValueChange` listeners and adding a new listener. For the example, I will do everything in code to remove any sort of confusion.

All that is left is to map our retrieved values our slider outputs to some desired output. As your desired output seem to just be alphanumeric values, you can actually make the solution even easier by knowing that taking an integer value and adding the character 'a' to it will result in the corresponding alphanumeric value (where 0 is mapped to a and 25 to z).

```
[SerializeField] private Slider slider = null;

private void Start()
{
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { SliderValueChangedCallback(); });
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when our slider value changes
/// </summary>
private void SliderValueChangedCallback()
{
    // grab out numeric value of the slider - cast to int as the value should be a whole number
    int numericSliderValue = (int)slider.value;

    // now, plot our value to an alphanumeric one
    char alphaNumericValue = (char)(numericSliderValue + 'a');

    Debug.Log(alphaNumericValue);
}
```

Now this solution will only work if you want your outputted values to be alphanumeric values. If you want a more modular solution, here is one:

```
[SerializeField] private Slider slider = null;
[SerializeField] private Text currentValue = null;

[SerializeField] private List<string> yourValueList = new List<string> { "First Message", "Second Message", "Third Value", "4 for some reason", "the letter 6" };

private void Start()
{
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { SliderValueChangedCallback(); });

    // assuring that our slider is setup properly to map values
    slider.minValue = 0;
    slider.maxValue = yourValueList.Count - 1;
    slider.wholeNumbers = true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when our slider value changes
/// </summary>
private void SliderValueChangedCallback()
{
    // grab out numeric value of the slider - cast to int as the value should be a whole number
    int numericSliderValue = (int)slider.value;

    // debugging - do whatever you want with this value
    currentValue.text = yourValueList[numericSliderValue];
}
```

Here is a gif of it in action:

[image: Example 3]

Let me know if you have questions. I was unsure if you visually want to show these markers on the slider as well, but that can also be done using the normalized positions and a horizontal layout group.